# Only use already existing files(python)

Tags: python, file, save

Ok so I have a the name of a file as an raw input. But I the code to only use an already existing file and not and not be able to type in everything and just create new files.

So how can I make the program only use an already existing file and NOT create a new one if the input is wrong?

```
lista = {"police":"911"}
functiontext = raw_input("call function ")
arguments = raw_input("input file name ")

def save(lista,arguments):
     filen = arguments
     spara = lista
     fil = open(filen + ".txt","w")

for keys, values in spara.items():

        spara_content = keys + ": " + values + "\n"


        fil.write(spara_content)
        fil.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [os.path.exists() or os.path.isfile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to test if the file is there. For example:

```
def save(lista,arguments):
    filen = arguments
    spara = lista
    fname = filen + ".txt"
    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        fil = open(filen + ".txt","w")
    else:
        print("The file {} does not exist, skipping".format(fname))
```

Comment: Ok i should have been a little more clear... is there a way to do it without using os? Or is this pretty much the only way to do it if you are new to programming?

Comment: All of the modules like os are either just pure python underneath, or wrappers for system calls and stuff like that. So in effect, yes you can, but you'd be reinventing the wheel. Do you have a good reason to not use os?

Comment: sorry for late reply but ehm... we aren't allowed to use pickle... so i dunno if we are allowed to use os....

Comment: Disallowing pickle is a bit of a strange restriction, it doesn't seem to have much relevance to this problem. I would say that unless otherwise specified, the os module is perfectly appropriate to use.